# MongoEngine save is slow

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have an embedded document with a size of 180K, but it takes about 50S to store in Mongo. I would like to know how to optimize this storage time

Below is some time analysis of my program. It can be seen that the main reason is that `document.py:548(_clear_changed_fields)` calls consume time. After I set the `modle.save(force_insert=True)`, the efficiency did not improve

```
 Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   53.977   53.977 document.py:333(save)
 465601/1    0.922    0.000   53.732   53.732 document.py:548(_clear_changed_fields)
     1552    0.621    0.000   53.629    0.035 document.py:586(_nestable_types_clear_changed_fields)
1861803/465601   23.878    0.000   50.606    0.000 document.py:639(_get_changed_fields)
  8396029    3.468    0.000    7.966    0.000 datastructures.py:378(get)
 31703568    6.885    0.000    6.885    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
```

Comment: Would you show some of your code?  There are a lot of calls to `document.py:639(_get_changed_fields)` for one document.